# ASP.Net Web Site Administration Tools not working

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sqlconnection

I am working with ASP.Net Web Site Administration Tools. The web.config worked fine for a period of time, but today after i just opened it and clicked on ASP.NET Configuration on Web Site menu, the First page opens which contains three links, when i click on the first link which is "Security", i get the following error

```
A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The wait operation timed out.)
```

What should I check to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this thread on [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/729323/visual-studio-11-beta-installation-disabled-my-abillity-to-connect-remote-ms-sql-server-but-not-local-databases#tabs). It seem to have a couple of solutions for the error message you get.

The solution in that thread seems to be to "remove non-IFS LSP installed Winsock Catalog Provider". See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2568167 for more details.

Comment: I uninstalled Visual Studio 2012 and Microsoft Entity Framework 4.5 and re-installed Visual Studio 2010, then i got fixed. is there any thing wrong with having these software together?

Comment: Great, but maybe the problems will occur again if you install them again. If they do then try the solution in the Microsoft support link that I added in my answer.